# awk determine unique rows based on subset of columns

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I'm looking to return rows in a csv that are unique for a specified subset of columns.

Example data:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
A,10,50,2017
A,10,05,2017
B,20,30,2017
B,20,03,2017
C,30,100,2017
C,30,111,2017
C,30,100,2016
C,40,111,2016
C,30,123,2015
```

This command outputs the unique values of a single column (column 1 in this case):

```
awk -F , '{ a[$1]++ } END { for (b in a) { print b } }' file
```

returns

```
Col1
A
B
C
```

I'd like a command to do this for 2 columns or n columns.

Desired output for unique rows using 2 columns (Col1 and Col3):

```
Col1,Col3
A,50
A,05
B,30
B,03
C,100
C,111
C,123
```

For Col1 and Col4

```
Col1,Col4
A,2017
B,2017
C,2017
C,2016
C,2015
```

For 3 columns Col1, Col2, and Col3

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
A,10,50
A,10,05
B,20,30
B,20,03
C,30,100
C,30,111
C,40,111
C,30,123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print a certain column, let's say column 1 and 4, simply run:

`awk -F',' '{print $1, $4}' file`

The command here is to ask `awk` to print the designated column separated by the ','

You can change the column number, add / remove the $NUM to get different columns.

Combined with `sort`, you will get the unique rows:

`awk -F',' '{print $1, $4}' file | sort -u`

The `-u` flag removes duplicate items from the output.

Comment: Works as requested and can be modified for n columns, e.g. `awk -F',' '{print $1, $3, $4}' file | sort |uniq`. Upvote cast but not displaying due to my low rep.

Comment: I believe you can also use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`

Comment: @grooveplex oh right! Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by combining the column-values in the hash key, e.g. assuming your input is sorted, this one-pass solution works for column 1-3:

```
awk '!h[$1,$2,$3]++ { NF--; print }' FS=, OFS=, data.csv
```

Output:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
A,10,50
A,10,05
B,20,30
B,20,03
C,30,100
C,30,111
C,40,111
C,30,123
```

For columns 1 and 4, do something like this:

```
awk '!h[$1,$4]++ { print $1, $4 }' FS=, OFS=, data.csv
```

Output:

```
Col1,Col4
A,2017
B,2017
C,2017
C,2016
C,2015
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Python

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
col_nums = sys.argv[2:]
if not col_nums:
    sys.exit()

rows_unique = []
for row in open(filename).read().splitlines():
    cells = row.split(',')
    # Select cells in row based on given column numbers.
    cells_selected = [cells[int(col_num)] for col_num in col_nums]
    row_selected = ','.join(cells_selected)
    if row_selected not in rows_unique:
        print(row_selected)
        rows_unique += [ row_selected ]
```

Save as an executable script, then call (note that columns are zero-indexed):

```
$ get_unique_rows_per_column.py file 0 2
Col1,Col3
A,50
A,05
B,30
B,03
C,100
C,111
C,123
```